# php DOM getAttribute

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domdocument, getattribute

Alright, so I have an odd case here that I just can't figure out.

I want to parse a list on a website. The HTML looks somewhat like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<ul id="foo">
    <li data-text="item 1">Blabla</li>
    <li data-text="item 2">Blabla</li>
    <li data-text="item 3">Blabla</li>
    <li data-text="item 4">Blabla</li>
</ul>
<!-- ... -->
```

Now I want to grab all the list items. I use the DOMDocument-class for that. So far, that works out just fine:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

if (!$dom->loadHTML($html)) {
    die ('Could not parse...');
}

$list = $dom->getElementById('foo');
$items = $list->childNodes;
foreach ($items as $item) {
     print_r($item);
}
```

But now, I'm looking for a simple method to read out the `data-text` attribute. What I did was:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
     echo $item->getAttribute('data-text');
}
```

This works just fine for the very first item, but then it crashes the foreach-loop. The output is:

> item 1
>   Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute()
>   in example.php on line 44

What I don't get here is how calling the `getAttribute` method changes the context of the foreach loop. So here are two questions:

1. How can invoking the method screw up my foreach loop? Secondly,
   what's the most elegant workaround?
2. I realized I could loop through `$item->attributes with` yet another
   foreach method, then compare the attribute name to `data-text` and
   read the value in case of a match, but there surely has to be a
   better way to do so?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the `ul` has text nodes as children along with the `li`s textnodes do not have attribute therefore you get an error. just test if the child is an element node before you try to access its attribute

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
         if ($item->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
         echo $item->getAttribute('data-text');
}
```

You can also use [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php), although if you have nested lists the `li`s in them will also be selected.

```
$items = $list->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->getAttribute('data-text');
}
```

Comment: Ah, there we go. It all makes sence now. Since the lists are indeed nested, comparing the nodeType seems the perfect way to go. Thanks a million!

Comment: If you var_dump the nodeType you will get integers, check out the int values at https://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php